# focusout happening immediately after focus()

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dom-events

I am creating 'typeform like' form, that scrolls one input element at a time.

`name -> email -> phone -> address -> note`
(codepen [here](https://codepen.io/ksjd/pen/abNeQNy))

With the code below, I have the situation that after entering value for `phone` and pressing enter, `address` gets skipped. Flow directly reaches `note`.
The reason is that `focusout` event gets fired, immediately after `target.find(".input-box").focus()` on `input#address.input-box`.

<s>I do not understand what is causing `focusout` to be fired.

Can anyone explain? (and how to stop it from happening).</s>

The intent is to have `phone` element scroll after user enters the input on mobile. On iOS for example, there is no Enter key for phone entries, only 'Done'.
I use `focusout` since it the event fired on pressing 'Done'. But it is too broadly fired, to properly work with.
Is there a better way to achieve the expected behavior?

HTML:

```html
<!-- ... -->
  <div class="flex-container">
    <form novalidate="">
      <div class="input-block flex-item" id="input-block-name" style="display: inherit;">
        <div class="label">name</div><input class="input-box" type="text" id="name">
      </div>
      <div class="input-block flex-item" id="input-block-email" style="display: none;">
        <div class="label">email</div><input class="input-box" type="email" id="email">
      </div>
      <div class="input-block flex-item" id="input-block-phone" style="display: none;">
        <div class="label">mobile</div><input class="input-box" type="tel" id="phone">
      </div>
      <div class="input-block flex-item" id="input-block-address" style="display: none;">
        <div class="label">address</div><input class="input-box" type="text" id="address">
      </div>
      <div class="input-block flex-item" id="input-block-note" style="display: none;">
        <div class="label">note</div><input class="input-box" type="text" id="note">
      </div>
<!-- ... -->
    </form>
<!-- ... -->
```

JS:

```js
$(".input-box").first().focus();
$(".input-block")
  .not($(document.activeElement.parentElement))
  .css({ display: "none" });

$(window).on(
  "keyup wheel focusout",
  _.debounce((event) => {
    var current = $(":visible").closest(".input-block");

    // next
    if (
      event.key === "Enter" ||
      event.originalEvent.deltaY > 0 ||
      (event.type == "focusout" && event.target == $("#phone")[0])
    ) {
      var target = $(":visible").closest(".input-block").next();

      target.css({ display: "inherit" });
      target.find(".input-box").focus();
      current.css({ display: "none" });
    }

    // prev
    if (event.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
      var target = $(":visible").closest(".input-block").prev();

      target.css({ display: "inherit" });
      target.find(".input-box").focus();
      current.css({ display: "none" });
    }
  }, 30)
);
```

*EDIT: refined the question, after first response.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT by OP: what 'solved' the issue, was to use `blur` event (see comments).

I believe your issue is with this line (in the if condition):

```
(event.type == "focusout" && event.target == $("#phone")[0])
```

With each scroll there will be a 'focusout' type from the previous input. When you scroll from phone to address, the phone input box has a type of 'focusout' and the above referenced code condition is true, hence why the result of the condition is happening twice.

Fully removing the above referenced line should resolve your issue.

Comment: I know it comes from here. Question is *what triggers `focusout`*. Are you sure scroll after prev input causes it? this event isn't fired when scrolling from name -> email -> phone. Above piece of code is to handle `focusout` after user enters the value in mobile and presses 'Done' (there being no Enter in telephone entry on iOS for example)

Comment: I put a console.log(event.type) just above your condition on your codepen and the 'focusout' event happens on every input (by scrolling and by pressing the enter key)

Comment: You are right. And I need the scroll only *after* the user enters phone input. Is there another event to handle such behaviour? `focusout` seems to be too broad.

Comment: have you tried using `blur`? I think the difference between `blur` and `focusout` is that `blur` does not bubble, whilst `focusout` does